# FQL multiqueries without returning everything

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-fql

I'm using multi queries with FQL, I have 3 queries actually. 
The third one is the one that interests me the most, however Facebook returns the result of the previous queries first, which means more overhead for me to process and more time to stream in the result. Is there a way to limit Facebook into only sending the result set of the 3rd query?

```
JSONqueries["query1"] = encodeURIComponent('SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()');
JSONqueries["query2"] = encodeURIComponent('SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM #query1)');
JSONqueries["query3"] = encodeURIComponent('SELECT eid, start_time, end_time, update_time, location, venue FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM #query2) and privacy=\'OPEN\'');
```

Comment: If you provide the queries I can help you construct just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are. But it's still too complex and therefore extremely slow.

SELECT eid, start_time, end_time, update_time, location, venue FROM event WHERE eid IN(SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me())) and privacy="OPEN"

Comment: Ah! I see what you did there! Perfect!